# Netbook Screen Resolution on OpenSuse

Tags: resolution, netbook, opensuse

I've just installed OpenSUSE 11.1 on my [Elonex Webbook](http://www.elonex.com/products/webbook_spec.shtm) as I want to start playing with Mono.

Unfortunately, there seems to be some problem with the video card, and it only seems to recognise it as VESA, and won't give me a higher resolution than 800x600.

The video card (VIA Unichrome Pro II apparently), will support 1024x600, but OpenSuse won't have it.

I have been able to successfully run this netbook on 1024x600 on Windows (XP and Win7), and on Ubuntu, however, I'd much rather use OpenSuse as its Novell backed (as is Mono...)

Would appreciate any suggestions, and please bear in mind, I'm a newbie on Linux (at the moment)....

Oh, and I have tried changing the xorg.conf file following [these instructions](http://webbookblog.com/reinstalling-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-webbook/) but that also didn't work.

Have also installed the openChrome driver from [here](http://www.logix.cz/michal/devel/suse-openchrome/index.xp?show_selected=1&msgid=5557#feedback_form) but that also doesn't give me anything.

I have also tried changing the screen resolution in the graphics app on opensuse, and that, while it does say 1024x600, and tests ok, doesn't boot on it.

Many thanks

Nick

EDIT: The output of the xrandr command is

```
Screen 0: minimum 800 x 600, current 800 x 600, maximum 800 x 600

default connected 800x600+0+0 0m x 0mm

   800x600        75.0*
```

EDIT2: I've also tried putting Ubuntu Netbook Remix on there, and that doesn't allow me to complete the install, as it changes the graphics mode to something I can't see. I guess I need to install, using a monitor, then change it... Shame I can't get opensuse working though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the xorg.conf file with

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

and made the following changes:

```
Section"Device"
    Identifier "Configured Video Device"
    Driver "openchrome"
    Option "PanelSize" "1024x600"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Indentifier "Configured Monitor"
    DisplaySize 221 129 # 117 DPI @ 1024x600 Opiton "noDDC"
EndSection
```

which appears to work quite well. However, I have swapped to Ubuntu (9.1 now), which has the openchrome driver for the Elonex Webbook included.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the output of the command 'xrandr', it will list your available resolution, the same command can also be used to manually set the resolution using 'xrandr -s 1024x768' or the resolution you desire.

Comment: Hi there, I've updated the question to add that in. Cheers! :)